# Kubernete Pod cannot resolve DNS address but can reach it (example curl google.com fails, curl ip is ok)

Tags: networking, server, docker, cluster, kubernetes

I'm just starting out and i've been learning kubernetes since couple of weeks ago, i'm using a plain installation of microk8's with addons dns metallb enabled, and a simple pod with alpine with curl pkg added to make some tests.

Everything works fine, deployments, nodes, comunication within pods from same namespaces as well as other namespaces.
But i cannot reach internet within a pod using dns name.
for example:

`curl google.com -> curl: (7) Failed to connect to google.com port 80 after 14 ms: Couldn't connect to server`

while

`curl 142.250.184.78 -> OK`

Same goes for ping command, with the strange add that it resolves the dns google.com in 127.0.0.1:

`ping google.com -> 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms`

while

`ping 142.250.184.78 -> 64 bytes from 142.250.184.78: seq=0 ttl=114 time=8.997 ms`

I really don't know where to go, i've tried looking into calico for kubernetes but i just can't figure it out myself, any help is appreciated.

Setup Used:
Dedicated machine with Ubuntu 22.04.1 inside a home-network
Out of the box microk8s installation with just dns metallb addon
Simple container with curl pkg installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was a problem of dns.
Kubernetes was trying to resolve a dns inside /etc/resolv.conf
it was something like 'homenettelecom.com' which dunno why it couldn't let me out of the network.
Upon removing it everything started working properly.
Also had to remove the symlink for /etc/resolv.conf because some application (i suppose also kubernetes) was constantly re-applying that conifg.